# Display image in JOGL

Tags: java, image, jogl

I'm currently working on an assignment where I need to create a game in JOGL, it's going pretty well, but I've run into a problem:

I want to create a menu function that can be accessed by pressing ESC ingame, when ESC is pressed the display function needs to stop displaying the game and start displaying the menu. The menu consists of a background image with some text overlay.

This is how I tried to implement the menu function, but I haven't managed to let it show anything else than the clear color:

```
public class OptionsMenu 
{
    public void display(GL gl) {

        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_PROJECTION);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();
        gl.glOrtho(0, 300, 300, 0, 0, 1);
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glDisable(GL.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        gl.glClearColor(1f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f);  
        gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        gl.glBlendFunc (GL.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); 
        gl.glEnable (GL.GL_BLEND);
        BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
        int w = 0;
        int h = 0;
        try {
            bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(OptionsMenu.class.getResource("menuBackground.jpg")); //The menu background
            w = ceilingPow2(bufferedImage.getWidth());
            h = ceilingPow2(bufferedImage.getHeight());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WritableRaster raster = 
                Raster.createInterleavedRaster (DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE,
                        w,
                        h,
                        4,
                        null);
        ComponentColorModel colorModel=
                new ComponentColorModel (ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_sRGB),
                        new int[] {8,8,8,8},
                        true,
                        false,
                        ComponentColorModel.TRANSLUCENT,
                        DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);
        BufferedImage img = 
                new BufferedImage (colorModel,
                        raster,
                        false,
                        null);

        Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();
        g.drawImage(bufferedImage, null, null);

        DataBufferByte imgBuf =
                (DataBufferByte)raster.getDataBuffer();
        byte[] imgRGBA = imgBuf.getData();
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(imgRGBA);
        bb.position(0);
        bb.mark();

        gl.glBindTexture(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 13);
        gl.glPixelStorei(GL.GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL.GL_CLAMP);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL.GL_CLAMP);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameteri(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexEnvf(GL.GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL.GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL.GL_REPLACE);
        gl.glTexImage2D (GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, w, h, 0, GL.GL_RGBA, 
                GL.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bb);

        gl.glEnable(GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glBindTexture (GL.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 13);
        gl.glBegin (GL.GL_POLYGON);
        gl.glTexCoord2d (0, 0);
        gl.glVertex2d (0, 0);
        gl.glTexCoord2d(1,0);
        gl.glVertex2d (w, 0);
        gl.glTexCoord2d(1,1);
        gl.glVertex2d (w, h);
        gl.glTexCoord2d(0,1);
        gl.glVertex2d (0, h);
        gl.glEnd ();    
        gl.glFlush();
    }
    private static int ceilingPow2(int n) {
        int pow2 = 1;
        while (n > pow2) {
            pow2 = pow2<<1;
        }
        return pow2;
    }
}
```

This code is based of this tutorial: http://wiki.tankaar.com/index.php?title=Displaying_an_Image_in_JOGL_(Part_1)

I'm calling upon the OptionsMenu like so:

```
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) 
    {
        GL gl = drawable.getGL();
        GLU glu = new GLU();

        if(state.equals("optionsMenu"))
        {
            if(menu == null)
                menu = new OptionsMenu;

            menu.display(gl);
        } 
        else 
        {   
            // Calculating time since last frame.
            Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();      
            long currentTime = now.getTimeInMillis();
            int deltaTime = (int)(currentTime - previousTime);
            previousTime = currentTime;

            // Update any movement since last frame.
            updateMovement(deltaTime);
            updateCamera();

            gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            glu.gluLookAt( camera.getLocationX(), camera.getLocationY(), camera.getLocationZ(), 
                    camera.getVrpX(), camera.getVrpY(), camera.getVrpZ(),
                    camera.getVuvX(), camera.getVuvY(), camera.getVuvZ() );

            // Display all the visible objects of MazeRunner.
            for( Iterator<VisibleObject> it = visibleObjects.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
                it.next().display(gl);
            }

            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glFlush();
        }
    }
```

It doesn't throw any errors, it just won't display the image. It does however show the clear color gl.glClearColor(1f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f); defined in the display function of the OptionsMenu

I'm pretty much stumped and I have no idea how I'm going to fix this.

Sorry for the long post, but I'd be REALLY grateful if someone would help me.

Answer (score 0):

I guess clear color buffers `gl.glClear(GL.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );`
 should be placed at the begining of display method of OptionsMenu.

I have few advices for example posted code above:

- Change scope of the `GLU glu = new GLU();`, because `glu` assigned each time when opengl display callback method called.
- Also move `gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);` right before if statement, and do not use every objects display method (e.g OptionsMenu.display()). Try keep it single.
- Use TextureIO to upload texture, and if its possible just upload it once then use that texture in your display method. Texture loading process has great overhead.